# Create delivery stream (Firehose) from data stream (Kinesis) to OpenSearch AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-opensearch

I am trying to create a Delivery Stream (Firehose) in AWS Console, with these options:

- Source: Amazon Kinesis Data Streams
- Destination: Amazon OpenSearch Service

The Amazon OpenSearch Service's Domain is an OpenSearch 2.3 version, with these options:

- Deployment type of "Development and testing"
- Compatibility mode Enabled
- t3.small.search instance type

But when I create the delivery stream, the following error occurs:

> Your delivery stream was not created
> Unable to create the delivery stream ------. Wait a few minutes and try again. If the problem persists, go to AWS Support Center .
> API response
> Elasticsearch domain arn:aws:es:------:domain/------ has an unsupported version: OpenSearch_2.3

What I am missing to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed nothing.
I have been able to confirm that the Firehose service is yet to support this new 2.3 OpenSearch version. I think AWS is aware about that and we can't have ETA for now.

Comment: Thanks! So all I have to do until AWS fix this, is downgrade the version of OpenSearch.

Comment: January 6, 2023 and is not yet supported the OpenSearch v2.3